# The simple p2os (pioneer) gazebo simulation example stopped working on electric

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, ros-electric, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The simple p2os (pioneer) gazebo simulation example stopped working on *electric*.
On *dimamondback* it was possible to simulate a pioneer robot by running:

```
roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch
```

and to control it by:

```
rosrun erratic_teleop erratic_keyboard_teleop
```

On electric it stopped working, *rostopic* showed me that there is no publisher for **\cmd_vel**.
Weird is that the very similar example from the [erratic robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/TeleopErraticSimulation)  works.

Had someone the same problem and maybe a solution?

I tried to debug the gazebo_plugin  gazebo_ros_diffdrive (gazebo_ros_diffdrive.cpp ) and it stucked there on line 71 *client->ConnectWait(serverId, GZ_CLIENT_ID_USER_FIRST)*;

Greetings
Max

Tested on Ubuntu 10.04 32bit and 11.04 64bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11539/the-simple-p2os-(pioneer)-gazebo-simulation-example-stopped-working-on-electric/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to VN!

It is working now!
I rewrote controller part in the pioneer3dx.xacro and replaced

```
<controller:differential_position2d name="controller1">
  <update>100</update>
  <leftJoint>base_right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
  <rightJoint>base_left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
  <wheelSeparation>0.39</wheelSeparation>
  <wheelDiameter>0.15</wheelDiameter>
  <torque>5</torque>
  <interface:position name="position_iface_0"/>
</controller:differential_position2d>
```

with

```
<controller:diffdrive_plugin name="differential_drive_controller" plugin="libdiffdrive_plugin.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <update>100</update>
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <leftJoint>base_right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
  <rightJoint>base_left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
  <wheelSeparation>0.39</wheelSeparation>
  <wheelDiameter>0.15</wheelDiameter>
  <torque>5</torque>
  <interface:position name="position_iface_0"/>
  <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
  <topicName>cmd_vel</topicName>
</controller:diffdrive_plugin>
```

And there where also some changes needed to the launch file:
The *Controller Manager* and the *Controller Manager* could be replaced by the *Robot state publisher*.

```
  <!-- Robot state publisher -->
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="" />
  </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on 2011-10-16**:
Hi Markus: Just curious to know if you are able to use pioneer model (your modified urdf/xacro file) to simulate in gazebo using navigation stack without any odometry error?? looking forward to hear from you.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-15**:
Can you share your setup? i am trying to setup similar simulation but couldnot do. problem : http://answers.ros.org/question/29759/p2os-gazebo-simulation-example-stopped-working-on

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Markus: pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch file doesn't have transmissions for swivel and castor wheel. you have to modify it little bit. you should use "erratic robot" differential drive plugin.

---

Originally posted by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) with karma: 373 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swagatk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4401/swagatk/) on 2013-03-26**:
Hi! Just wanted to let you know that your solution worked for me as well. I tested it on Fuerte running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit OS. However, I still have a small issue. The robot is little jumpy. I mean the robot castor wheel keeps vibrating.